Click on <a> tag is not being added to webview history
I have an app which renders its screens on a webview. We have recently found a very strange issue. whenever we click on any  tag links and press back button it doesnt go navigate to the screen where  tag is clicked.
App Open -> Screen 1 -> <a> tag click -> Screen 2 -> Press back -> App Closes

I am handling the back button as follows
if(webview.canGoback()){
  webview.goBack()
} else {
 super.onBackPressed()
}

This happens only for the first click on the  tag. from the second click onwards it is being added to the stack. and also it is observed that after clicking the  link the same has not been added to copyBackForwardList() it was showing only the first item.
Let me know if anyone knows the reason for this
